# is there any open source tool to migrate informatica Etl Script to Aws glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, migration, aws-glue, informatica, informatica-cloud

We are moving away from Informatica.

We have approximately 50 jobs and want to convert the old etl scripts in Informatica to AWS glue.

studied aws sct, but it's not useful.

We wanted it to be open source tool to do this job.

If open source is not an option, consider another solution.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer to this - depending on complexity and your requirements, i will answer.
I will assume, by saying informatica scripts you mean to say informatica mappings and not shell/cmd scripts.

Main challenge is informatica map logic is written partially in metadata and then rest is handled internally. You can not create single script to convert them automatically.

case 1 - very complex mapping to medium complex mapping - convert them manually. No tool can effectively convert them without any error. There are some non open source company which can help you in decomposing infa mappings but there is no built-in tool to replicate mappings.

case 2 - medium complex mapping to simple mappings -  There are some non open source company which can help you in decomposing infa mappings and build sql scripts automatically. You have to tune the sql scripts after testing.

case 3 - you want to use strict open sources - You need to spend time and effort to decompose infa mappings and recrreate them. YOu can create some sql to fetch mapping logic but its difficult to fetch all logic and recreate them using sql.

hope i can shed some light on this.